Use plotly to plot multiple pandas column with a dropdown menu to select column
I have a pandas dataframe for which I am trying to a plot bar graph using Plotly with a dropdown menu to select by the stock name column, referring this answer.
But I am unsure how do I add multiple columns to the updatemenus as the names of the columns could vary.
import plotly.graph_objects as go
# plotly setup
fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces, starting from First Column. Each column is a stock data.
for mycolumn in df.columns[1:]:
    fig.add_traces( go.Scatter(x=list(df.Quarters), y=list(df[mycolumn])) )

updatemenus = None

for mycolumn in df.columns[1:]:
    # construct menus
    updatemenus = [{'buttons': 
                    [{'method': 'update',
                      'label' : column, # what?
                      'args'  : [{'y': [values_1, values_1b]},] # what?
                     }
                    'direction': 'down',
                    'showactive': True,}
                  ]

# update layout with buttons, and show the figure
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()

The dataframe for ref:



Quarters
526433
AARTIIND
DEEPAKNTR
GREENPANEL
METROBRAND
MOLDTECH
MUFTI
MUTHOOTFIN
YASHO
ZENTEC




Mar-21



4.6
1.69







Jun-21
2.99
4.55
22.19
2.43

1.16

24.37
10.01
-0.14


Sep-21
3.77
4.14
18.65
5.47
1.89
1.3

24.97
12.44
0


Dec-21
4.3
20.01
17.78
5.14
3.69
0.59

25.91
12.71
-0.02


Mar-22
1.54
5.34
19.59
6.57
2.49
1.67

24.84
11.69
0.42


Jun-22
3.35
3.75
17.2
6.33
3.8
1.1

20.41
16.99
0.94


Sep-22
2.84
3.42
12.79
5.91
2.72
2.43
80.9
22.22
19.61
0.71


Dec-22
2.25
3.77
15.33
3.06
4.22
3.26
60.25
23.11
9.18
1.19


Mar-23
0.25
4.11
17.15
5.62
2.44
3.58
67.43
24.25
13.76
2.54


Jun-23
0.36
1.93
10.99
3.04
3.91
2.21
1.33
25.46
12.97
5.6


Sep-23
-1.59
2.51
15.04
3.34
2.92
2.86
4.35
26.39
10.23
1.82


Dec-23
-0.19
3.42
14.81
2.82
3.52
2.47
2.42
27.49
11.88
3.64


Mar-24
-2.59
3.64
18.61
2.43
6.05
2.26
1.1
28.37
15.74
4.16


Jun-24
2.83
3.78
14.85

3.4
1.81
1.51
28.99
-2.16
9.14




As mentioned in the linked post:

'y' = [values_1] where values_1 is a list in itself.

So, we need 'y': [df[col]] for each col in df.iloc[:, 1:]. For the label value use col itself. Also make sure only to add a trace for your first column, as this will give us the result for the first selection.
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

# add trace only for first stock
x = df['Quarters']
y = df['526433']
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y))

# create `list` with a `dict` for each column
buttons = [{'method': 'update', 'label': col, 'args': [{'y': [df[col]]}]} 
           for col in df.iloc[:, 1:]]

# add menus
updatemenus = [{'buttons': buttons,
                'direction': 'down',
                'showactive': True,}]

# update layout with buttons, and show the figure
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()

Output:

Data used
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Quarters': {0: 'Mar-21', 1: 'Jun-21', 2: 'Sep-21', 3: 'Dec-21', 4: 'Mar-22', 
                     5: 'Jun-22', 6: 'Sep-22', 7: 'Dec-22', 8: 'Mar-23', 9: 'Jun-23', 
                     10: 'Sep-23', 11: 'Dec-23', 12: 'Mar-24', 13: 'Jun-24'}, 
        '526433': {0: np.nan, 1: 2.99, 2: 3.77, 3: 4.3, 4: 1.54, 5: 3.35, 6: 2.84, 
                   7: 2.25, 8: 0.25, 9: 0.36, 10: -1.59, 11: -0.19, 12: -2.59, 13: 2.83}, 
        'AARTIIND': {0: np.nan, 1: 4.55, 2: 4.14, 3: 20.01, 4: 5.34, 5: 3.75, 6: 3.42,
                     7: 3.77, 8: 4.11, 9: 1.93, 10: 2.51, 11: 3.42, 12: 3.64, 13: 3.78}, 
        'METROBRAND': {0: 1.69, 1: np.nan, 2: 1.89, 3: 3.69, 4: 2.49, 5: 3.8, 6: 2.72, 
                       7: 4.22, 8: 2.44, 9: 3.91, 10: 2.92, 11: 3.52, 12: 6.05, 13: 3.4}
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Thanks, this works! Could you please explain again why only one trace fixes this? why not all traces?

You only need (and: want) one trace, because when you select a different stock, your trace gets updated with (in this case) new y-values. Suppose you would add another trace, you'll find that in the beginning you start with 2 traces, but after selection, only the last trace gets updated, and the first trace becomes empty for y, since you only have 1 set of new y-values (for your new stock).

Thanks! And curious if the buttons could be applied on two subplots?

Sure it can! Here's a helpful post on that. If you have difficulty implementing such a solution, please open a new question, as that option rather falls outside the scope of your current question. Good luck!
